# greatest common divisor (python)

Tags: python, greatest-common-divisor

I'm trying to get my code to print out my greatest common devisor. Technically my code should work, but it always goes one step firther until x = 0 even though it should print x = *gcd*
Everything you see in the code kind of has to stay as it is structure base, due to the assignement of my school.
Meaning I have to print out x and have a while loop with r != 0 and so on...
Whatever you most likely know how to fix it without me overexplaining my code xD

```
def ggt2(x, y):
    r = 1
    while r != 0:       #I have to use a while loop
        if x < y:
            r = x % y
            x = y
            y = r
            print(x)    #here it prints nothing at all
        elif x > y:
            r = x % y
            y = x
            x = r
            print(x)    #here it prints x = 0
x = input()
y = input()
ggt2(int(x), int(y))
```

EDIT:
Here is the pseudo code we were given. This is basically the structure I have to follow. We were also told to switch x <-> y if x < y.

```
GCD :var X,Y,R: int;
input X,Y;
R:=1;
while R ≠ 0 do
R:=X mod Y; X:=Y; Y:=R;
od;
output X.
```

Comment: If everything has to stay, how are you supposed to fix it?

Comment: Your last print will always be `0` for the `x > y` case because you keep looping as long as `r != 0`, and what you are printing is basically `r` at the end of each loop.

Comment: You're printing `x` after you do the reassignments, but before you test it the next time through the loop.

Comment: I mean the basic structure, so stuff like r = 1, the while loop and the way r, x, and y are calculated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use math.gcd?

Comment: @FrankYellin yes there is xD I just updated my question where you can see the assignment we were given.

Comment: @superbrain I never changed it. The stuff we were given isn't python xD What else am I supposed to do then trying to translate it into python. The pseudo code are just the basic instructions I have to follow.

Comment: @superbrain well then it would be nice if you could tell me where cuz obviously I don't see it. You're not really helping rn xD

Comment: Your two `if` blocks are not equivalent, because you do `r = x % y` at the top of both of them. I think you want one of them to be `r = y % x`.  Also, you were given the hint to swap `x` and `y` so that `x` is always the larger number.  Why aren't you doing that?  If you were, you wouldn't need the `if` and to have your algorithm duplicated.

Comment: @Steve Do have a suggestion where else I should put the print(x) or what I could do different?

Comment: Well, now you have the whole answer from @mujjiga, assuming his code really works. - according to him, the order of `x` and `y` doesn't matter.  If that's the case, you can take the `if` and one of the two blocks of code out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def ggt2(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        t = b
        b = a % b
        a = t
    return a if a != 0 else None

a = int(input("Enter a: "))
b = int(input("Enter b: "))
print("Their GCD is: "+str(ggt2(a,b)))
```

This code was converted to Python from the pseudocode on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), with minor changes made.

There are some things wrong with your code.  Here is your give pseudocode:

```
GCD :var X,Y,R: int;
input X,Y;
R:=1;
while R ≠ 0 do
R:=X mod Y; X:=Y; Y:=R;
od;
output X.
```

What this says is:

1. Start `GCD`
2. create variables `X`, `Y`, and `R` of type `int` each
3. Input a value to `X` and `Y`
4. Set `R` to 1
5. While `R` is not equal to `0` do:
6. (in loop of 5) set `R` to `X` % `Y` (the remainder of `X` and `Y`)
7. (in loop of 5) set `X` to `Y`
8. (in loop of 5) set `Y` to `R`
9. End of loop started on statement 5 iteration
10. Print out `X`

This pseudocode converted to Python would be:

```py
def GCD():
    X = int(input("Enter X: "))
    Y = int(input("Enter Y: "))
    R = 1
    while R != 0:
        R = X % Y
        X = Y
        Y = R
    print(X)

GCD()
```

Try to figure out how this works, and tell me in the comments if it worked for you!

Comment: Thanks so much! It actually works. Kind of silly of me that I did it so complicated..!

Comment: @Gunn3r : Thank you for accepting this answer!  I hope you do well on that assignment of yours! 

Answer (score 0):

The pseudocode you have given is called Euclidean algo. It is division based and the order of x and y does not matter.

```
def ggt2(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        t = b
        b = a % b
        a = t
    return a

ggt2(24, 60)
ggt2(60, 24)
```

Output:

```
12
12
```

The order matters for subtraction based algo and thats why you are asked to switch `x,y` if `x < y`

Read [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to understand the both the algos.

Comment: Thanks, but now I still don't really know how to or where to put the print(x)... I'll still have a look into the wiki but it seemed like it would only help me understanding the calculation not more :/

Comment: Sorry @Gunn3r cant help you any further. It up to you to learn and figure out what to do next. Next steps are trivial.